# files are saving into program files insted of program files(x86)

Tags: windows-10

Can any one help me...

1. Why my files are going into programfiles folder even though I am using 32-bit OS on 64-bit architecture.
2. I have two folders

   - programfiles
   - Programfiles(x86)

Comment: there's neither programfiles nor Programfiles(x86) by default on any Windows. And obviously if you're using 32-bit Windows then there won't be "Program Files (x86)"

Comment: If you have two folders, "Program Files" and "Program Files x86", then you have a 64-bit operating system installed.  32-bit version of Windows DO NOT have a folder called "Program Files x86" unless it was created by a user or an application that wasn't behaving itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an 32-bit OS, it will only use one folder called Program Files.

If you have a 64-bit OS, then it will have 2 folders, where confusingly, the 32-bit Program Files folder changes to Program Files (x86).

Some installers don't check if the OS is actually 32 bit or not and just assume the OS is 64 bit and install to the wrong folder, which is why you get the Program Files (x86) folder, but you should not have this.

That said, it doesn't really matter in which folder the program is stored, other than that it may be a bit confusing when you search for the program. Therefor, the easiest is to right-click the shortcut and choose `open target` to always get your explorer to open in the correct location.